# Removing elements from a list in R with duplicated subelements

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R with several attributes inside, say:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$membership
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 3
[[2]]$csize
[1] 4 3 2
[[3]]$no
[1] 3

[[2]]
[[1]]$membership
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 3 3 4 4
[[2]]$csize
[1] 3 3 3 2
[[3]]$no
[1] 4

[[3]]
[[1]]$membership
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 4 4 4
[[2]]$csize
[1] 2 4 2 3
[[3]]$no
[1] 4
```

and so on.

However, some elements of the list have the same `$no`. For example, for element `[[1]]`, I have `[[1]][[3]]$no [1]3`; for element `[[2]]`, I have `[[2]][[3]]$no [1] 4`; for element `[[3]]`, I have `[[3]][[3]]$no [1] 4`; for element `[[4]]`, I have `[[4]][[3]]$no [1] 5`.

How can I keep all the elements of the list with different `$no`? Thank you!

Comment: Please this is the kind of dataset that *really* needs to be posted using `dput` or in a way that allow us to recreate it. Edit the question with the output of `dput(list)`, where `list` is the name of your list.

Comment: Ok! Tried to write it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following will do it.
First, create a list with the same structure as yours.

```
lst <- lapply(1:3, function(x) list(membership = 1 + x, csize = 2 + x, no = 12 + (x > 1)))
```

Now see which elements have duplicated `no` vectors and subset it.

```
inx <- !duplicated(sapply(lst, function(x) x$no))
lst[inx]
```